# Why does getActualTypeArguments return Object instead of Integer for Option[Int]?

Tags: scala, reflection, type-erasure

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the type parameter of Option when the type parameter is Int

I tried the following code:

```
class TestClass {
  val intField: Option[Int] = Some(1)
}

val cls = new TestClass
val field = cls.getDeclaredField("intField")
val typeParams = field.getGenericType.asInstanceOf[ParameterizedType].getActualTypeArguments
```

typeParams gives me java.lang.Object

my question is how do I get it to return java.lang.Integer to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exact generic type information is lost at run-time. See [Reflecting generics](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860) and note:

> > ...while the JVM *will not track the actual type arguments for instances* of a generic class, it does track the actual type arguments for *subclasses of generic classes*.

There are no *subclasses* here -- hence the reason for `Object` and not `Integer`. Perhaps look into [Manifests (a Scala trick for implicit reified types)](http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html)?

Happy coding.

Comment: @shangc Odd... scala still mystifies me :(